# Android: How to create oval horizontal scrolling tabs from Google Play

Tags: android, android-viewpager, material-design, android-tabhost, android-tablayout

how can I create this (Top Charts, Games,...):

[image: Google Play]

Exists some library for this? How is this component called? Or should I use `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`?

Comment: Those are probably just buttons with custom drawables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As cricket-007 recommended I'm using for this buttons in `HorizontalScrollView` and it's exactly the same.

Comment: does this view can be consider as tabs inside tabs ?